# Missing an attribute

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have double-checked my DB several times and see no problem, but when I run this code one record is missing when it meets the criteria.

The question is "Find the names of employees who have worked on project 2 but not on project 3" but I can't even get it to recognize all three records that have worked on project 2. It only pulls two of the records.

```
SELECT FNAME, LNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE (SELECT PNO
               FROM WORKSON 
               WHERE SSN = ESSN AND PNO = 2);
```

---

```
ESSN    PNO
666884444   3
123456789   2
453453453   2
333445555   2
333445555   3
```

here is my result

```
FNAME   LNAME
John    Smith
Franklin    Wong
```

there is another person who worked on project 2, but does not appear here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is that person present in `EMPLOYEE` table?

Comment: The error was in the employee table, how would I got about answering the question now?

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, two employees haven't worked for project 3:

```
123456789   2
453453453   2
```

So I believe that you mentioned about them:

```
FNAME   LNAME
John    Smith
Franklin    Wong
```

So why have you expected three names? For my knowledge, this employee worked both for 2 and 3 project, so should not appear:

```
333445555   2
333445555   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid. A `WHERE` clause is supposed to contain conditions. "Select a PNO" is not a condition.

You want to check whether entries exist for an employee and project. This is typically done with `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN`.

Supposing that PNO is the project number and ESSN is the employee number:

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM employee AS e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM workson AS w WHERE w.essn = e.essn AND w.pno = 2)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM workson AS w WHERE w.essn = e.essn AND w.pno = 3);
```

or

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM employee
WHERE essn IN (SELECT essn FROM workson WHERE pno = 2)
AND essn NOT IN (SELECT essn FROM workson WHERE pno = 3);
```

Comment: I've tested that exact query in MS Access 2016 and it surprisingly worked. Looks like it acts like EXISTS. My first thought was the same, but *here's my result* made me  give it a try.